Calculating Pion momenta for probing different structures using de Broglie wavelength
for the following question:

Consider a pion ($π^\pm$) scattering on a target. What pion momenta are needed to observe structures of the size of an atom
($10^{-10}$ m), an atomic nucleus ($10^{−14}$ m), or the proton ($10^{−15}$ m)?
For each case, consider if you need a relativistic treatment and explain your reasoning.

I know the Broglie wavelength is $h/p$. But for the $10^{-14}$ m and $10^{-15}$ m I need to treat it relativistically, how do I do this?

The de Broglie relation
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{p} \tag{1}$$
is already relativistically correct.
So you only need simple math to find the momentum $p$.
May be you confused it with the relation
between wavelength $\lambda$, velocity $v$ and rest mass $m$
$$\lambda=\frac{h\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}{mv}. \tag{2}$$
You can get this equation by combining the de Broglie relation (1)
with the relativistic momentum
$p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$
To solve (2) for the velocity $v$ you would indeed need
some more complicated math.

But for instance, if I use 10^-14 m, I get a momentum that leads to a velocity that is almost equal to c, if I use 10^-15m, I get a momentum that leads to a speed that is more then the speed of light. So something goes wrong here

@dutchrunner No, by using
$$p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
you always get a velocity $v$ smaller than $c$., regardless how big $p$ may be,
